# Android Parse JSON response

Tags: android, json, parsing

I dont know why i'm having so much issues with parsing this simple json:

```
{"status":0,"result":{"success":false,"message":"Error"}}
```

How would I get the **success** and **message** String?

```
    try {
        river = response.getJSONArray("result");

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < river.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = river.getJSONObject(i);

            if (c.has("message")) {
                message = c.getString("message");
                System.out.println("object_guid:"+message); }

            if (c.has("success")) {
                success = c.getString("success");
                System.out.println("subtype:"+success); }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
river = response.getJSONArray("result");
```

with

```
river = response.getJSONObject("result");
```

The `result` tag is a `JSONObject` and not a `JSONArray`

Answer (score 2):

Your `result` is not jsonarray, its an object.

`{"status":0,"result":{"success":false,"message":"Error"}}`

```
JSONObject river = response.getJSONObject("result"); 
String success = river.getString("success"); 
String message = river.getString("message");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your response your are not getting `JSONArray`. It contains `JSONObjects` only. So you need to get the `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`.

Try out as below:

```
                 river = response.getJSONObject("result");                                                                                
                         if (river.has("message")) {
                                  message = river.getString("message");                   
                                  System.out.println("object_guid:"+message); }

                           if (river.has("success")) {
                                  success = river.getString("success");                   
                                 System.out.println("subtype:"+success); }
                            }
```